# Basic question about equivalence relation on a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I have begun trying to work through W.R. Scott's *Group Theory* (which is kind of old, I guess, but hey, Dover is cheap!).  And it didn't take me long to get into trouble.  Scott says that if we have an equivalence relation $R$ on set $S$, then $S$ is the disjoint union of its equivalence classes w.r.t. $R$.

So let's say $S=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and

$R=\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2)\}$

Now, they way I see it, $R$ is symmetric, reflexive, and transitive, so it is an equivalence relation.  But the union of equivalence classes is $\{0,1,2\}$ so $S$ does not equal the union of equivalence classes.

We might "fix" this by saying that the domain of $R$ is not $S$ but is $\{0,1,2\}$ and we *can* recover *that set* through the union of equivalence classes.  So $R$ is not really on $S$ but is on this truncated version of $S$.  However, the definition of a relation $R$ being *on* a set $S$ is given as $R\subset S\times S$.  $R$ satisfies this definition, so it seems to me that $R$ is indeed on $S$, and we can't fix the problem in this way.

This seems so basic.  What am I missing?

Comment: An equivalence relation **must** be defined on the whole $\;S\times S\;$, as in reflexivity we require that **for all** $\;x\in S\;,\;\;xRx\;$ . Thus, your relation is *not* an equivalence one.

Comment: +1 for Dover. Since the books are inexpensive you can get several on the same topic. Then you can triangulate, combining different explanations to build your own intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$R$ is not reflexive on $S$: it does not contain $(3,3)$.

If you add $(3,3)$ to your set $R$ it will become an equivalence relation on $S$. And in that case you will see that there are exactly two equivalence classes which are disjoint and sum to whole $S$.

Comment: OK.  Get it now.  Thank you.